# Regex to get a list of strings within a pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a load of strings like this:

> .ls-resourceIcon .icon_xls_gif,
>   .ls-resourceIcon .icon_xlt_gif,
>   .ls-resourceIcon .icon_xlw_gif

I want to get the strings between icon_ and _gif into a comma separated list, so in this case "xls,xlt,xlw," (I can trim the trailing comma).

I have so far got this:

```
var regex = new RegExp("^.*icon_(.*)_gif.*$", "g");
var result = input.replace(regex, "$1,");
```

but that gives me

> xlw,

as a result, not all the matches.

What am I missing? Is there an easier way to do this that I haven't noticed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex is greedy, so the leading `.*` will grab everything up until the final `icon_xlw_gif`.  You need to make both sides non-greedy.  This might work:

```
var regex = new RegExp("icon_([A-Za-z]*)_gif", "g");
```

Remove the leading and trailing `.*`

Also replaced the `(.*)` with I think also now wouldn't work the way you intended it.

Comment: Ah I see. I'm getting the result ".ls-resourceIcon .xls,, .ls-resourceIcon .xlt,, .ls-resourceIcon .xlw," from your example though.

Comment: Got it, var regex = new RegExp("\.ls-resourceIcon \.icon_([A-Za-z]*)_gif,?", "g");